# Cannot use copy function with jdbc driver

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, copy, datagrip

Sorry about this question must be easy for some, but I need some help running a script in DataGrip with some images that are encoded in one of the columns of the table using the COPY Function that was given to me from a Linux machine. I am using windows.
My progresql version is

**PostgreSQL 10.4**, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 32-bit

I manage to add the JDBC driver **42.2.5** by adding it within the artifact tags in the XML file in

C:\Users[usr].DataGrip2018.1\config\jdbc-drivers\jdbc-driver.xml

But still, I have been getting this error for hours

***[57014] ERROR: COPY from stdin failed: The JDBC driver currently does not support COPY operations. Where: COPY [table], line 1
Details***

Any guidance or suggestions is more than welcome.

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.6.2
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 10.5 (Ubuntu 10.5-0ubuntu0.18.04)

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;
```

The COPY looks like this for one row

```
COPY public.qcq (gd, hg, qn, ar, photo, mus, id) FROM stdin;
f   f   lorem ipsum lorem?  4   \\xffT...this is an encripted image....0000000049454e44ae426082 t   8b4d6f0a-98b3-4dde-bbd4-f882cd39243b
\.
```

Comment: What does te code look like?

Comment: I edited the question... this is frustrating , thanks for reminding me about the code

Comment: DataGrip is based on JDBC driver, so if doesn't support COPY then DataGrip doesn't as well. Please use PSQL.